# moment format date error falls back to js Date() when using sequelize bulkCreate and testing with mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, sequelize.js, momentjs

I have an error when testing my app. I'm using moment version "2.22.2", and when I launch tests I have the following deprecation error:

> Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release. Please refer to http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/js-date/ for more info.
>
> Arguments:
> [0] _isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _useUTC: false, _l: undefined, _i: Invalid date, _f: undefined, _strict: undefined, _locale: [object Object]

The error is fired when I use Sequelize `destroy` and `bulkCreate` from `mocha` framework. These are the lines:

```
beforeEach(async function () {
  await db.sks.destroy({where: {}, truncate: true });
  await db.sks.bulkCreate(sksSeed);
});
```

I use moment only in two places in my code, one in a controller and one in a repository, both with this format: `const myDate = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD, hh:mm:ss');`

Even if I use `const myDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD, hh:mm:ss');`
or not using moment at all (ex.: `const myDate = new Date().toISOString().replace(/([^T]+)T([^\.]+).*/g, '$1 $2');`

I have the same error. If I comment out the line `await db.sks.bulkCreate(sksSeed);` I have no error, but the sksSeed file is a simple js file that did not use moment.

I don't know why I have this error only when I'm testing, however the db seems to be correctly seeded

Comment: Have you tried `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` (without the comma)

Comment: @doublesharp no, I have the same error

Comment: that's a parsing error so it is coming from passing a string to `moment` somewhere, not like the examples in your question.